# Gaps in Texture Baking

Tags: texture-baking

I am having a problem with texture baking and I have not been able to find a solution.  When the texture is baked, some of the islands do not line up perfectly with the new texture. I have tried changing so many different options, but still keep having the same problem.  I have also tried unwrapping it in different ways, too. 
Unfortunately if I just increase the margin (in the bake settings) the islands are fully filled, but if there is more then one color in the island the added pixels get their colors blended.
[image]
Zoomed in.  Texture not aligned with islands (margins set at 0).

[image]
This is what I get if I add margins to the texture bake.

I get interpolated colors inside island. Here the top portion is inside island. The only two colors should be white and pink. However the pixels added are interpolated colors. Notice the two pixels that are slightly inside the island that were added as I increased the margin.

Anyone have any suggestions for me?